# Boolean expressions in XSLT select statements

Tags: xslt

I have the following XSLT code that almost does what I want:

```
<xsl:variable name="scoredItems"
              select=
                  ".//item/attributes/scored[@value='true'] |
                  self::section[attributes/variable_name/@value='SCORE']/item |
                  .//item//variables//variable_name"/>
```

I want to change this to a more complicated boolean expression:

```
<xsl:variable name="scoredItems"
              select=
                  ".//item/attributes/scored[@value='true'] or
                  (self::section[variable_name/@value='SCORE']/item and 
                   (not (.//item/attributes/scored[@value='false']))) or
                  .//item//variables//variable_name"/>
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet     
at org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:832)     
at org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:618)
```

How do I fix this?  (Note that I'm using XSLT 1.0.)

Comment: What's the question?  What have you tried that doesn't work?  What error message are you getting?

Comment: Is there a problem? THe XPath expression seems a syntactically correct on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the default exception thrown by XSLT in Java is not very helpful. You'll need to implement an instance of [`ErrorListener`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/ErrorListener.html) and use its methods to capture and report the true XSLT problem. You can attach this `ErrorListener` using the `setErrorListener` method of your `TransformerFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

**I would greatly discourage anyone to write complicated expressions -- in any language!**

This is not an XSLT question at all. It is a general programming question and the answer is:

**Never write too complicated expressions** because they are challenging to write, read, test, verify, proof, change.

**Split a complicated expression onto a number of simpler expressions and assign them to different variables**. Then operate on these variables.